# Reverse lift mechanism

Tags: wheeled-robot, mechanism

I have made a RC robot from a wheelchair and I'm planning to attach a snow plow. I'm wondering if there is any mechanism that would be able to lift the plow when reversing. 
I have only 2 channel transmitter so I can't control the plow's movement through it so I was thinking of some mechanical lift that triggers when reversing.

Do you guys know about something I could use for it?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can!
If you share more specific information, I could give a more precise asnwer 
I guess you some kind of controller+receiver on your "wheelchair" and using a simple commercial RC?
Is the controller programmable?
Is one wheel controlled with one channel?
Do you want to drop the plow again remote controlled?

Comment: I'm using this controller http://www.instructables.com/id/RC-Riding-Lawnmower/step5/The-Sabertooth-2x25/ but I'm looking for some mechanical lift when dragging in reverse. Not electronic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your 2 channels control forward/backward and left/right.  But even if the 2 channels control forward/backward in each wheel (differential-drive style), it should still be possible to do what you are suggesting *electrically* instead of mechanically.

You should be able to read the input signal to the motors, decide whether those signals are commanding a "reverse" movement, and trigger your snow plow lift motor accordingly.

Comment: I understand that in theory it is possible but difficult in practice since I have no software to program the motor controller. There is just no way to detect the reverse from the sabertooth controller.

Comment: Can you update your original question with some sort of block diagram?  What prevents you from measuring the voltage (positive or negative) that goes from the sabertooth to the motors?